# Eloquent Model class not found in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, class, model, eloquent

I keep getting the following error:

> Use of undefined constant App - assumed 'App'

when I do:

```
  Route::get('/tasks', function () {
        $tasks = App / Task::all();
        return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
    });
```

This is how my model look like and it is located in the root of app directory:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Then if I change it to     `$tasks = 'App' / Task::all();` as it suggests then I get the class not found error:

> "Class 'Task' not found"

I have no clue what´s wrong, but as I am following a 5.4 tutorial and I am working with 5.6 there must be something different.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

`App\Task::all();`

`compact('tasks')`

Answer (score 1):

here, is correction

```
 $tasks = App\Task::all();
```

and

```
 return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
```

Comment: omg the issue was that I was using forward slash instead of the backslash.

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are referenced with backslashes (`\`). So in your case you should use `App\User::all();`

You can take a look at this page for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php